# Converting Sharepoint 2007 solution to 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, wss-3.0

Has anyone converted a Sharepoint 2007 solution to 2010 ?

I have a highly customized 2007 solution and need to upgrade it, i've seen some info on this, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143877/migrating-sharepoint-2007-to-2010) but my solution is more complex than a single web part.

I'm concerned about e.g. the following topics and hopefully someone can shed some light on it:

- Schema.xml, does it need to be upgraded to match new 2010 syntax ? I've done some testing on this and the top menu bar seems to be missing so I can't create new items
- Mapping the structure of the previous 12 hive. Is there any changes to the structure, can I just rename 12 to 14 and be done with it ?
- onet.xml, does it need to be upgraded similar to Schema.xml ?
- Workflows, will my old workflows be intact or are there any changes to the OM that I need to take into account ?

Finally is there some conversion tool out there that can help me resolve some of these issues ?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at my series of posts about [porting a SharePoint 2007 WSPBuilder Project to SharePoint 2010](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/03/porting-sharepoint-2007-wspbuilder.html). It doesn't deal with onet.xml, but it does explain how to move from the 12 hive to the 14 hive.

Comment: +1 excellent resource. I'm going to try and move between the hive like he's doing, will post an update on my results :)